# Get Information about NSF grant with grant number

Tags: nsf

Papers funded by NSF grants usually contain a phrase like "This research was supported by the National Science Foundation under Grants ENG-XXXXXX".

I wonder if it is possible to find some information about these grants with the grant numbers. I am interested in who applied for the grant, original proposal etc.

I tried to search on the NSF website with the specific grant number, but did not get any results.

Comment: https://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/advancedSearch.jsp

Answer (score 5):

Visit [research.gov](https://www.research.gov/research-portal/appmanager/base/desktop?_nfpb=true&_eventName=viewQuickSearchFormEvent_so_rsr)

> Research Spending & Results gives the public, the scientific community, and Congress insight into federally funded research. Research Spending & Results provides information about how federal research dollars are being spent, what research is being performed, and how the outcomes of research are benefiting society as a whole. Anyone can easily access, search, and sort information in new ways through Research.gov. Currently, information is available for NSF and NASA awards.

Search the award data.

Comment: Thanks, as far as I understood, this site contains data from 2007 onwards. Is there any database for awards from the 80ties?

Comment: @arved - I suspect nobody has thought it worthwhile or cost effective to go back and add that information. The 80's were a long time ago, particularly with respect to putting things on the internet...

Comment: @arved Many older grants are in the NSF award search.

Answer (score 1):

Often, you can find the relevant pages from the NSF by simply googling the grant number. That never failed for me, at least.

> Is there any database for awards from the 80ties?

This is more difficult; you probably won't be able to find things on the web. Maybe you can check with your university's library to see if they have any (physical paper copy) books of historical NSF grants. I am often surprised by what physical books, journals, etc. they have on hand in storage somewhere at my university.